# selfsigned https cert

Tags: linux, mysql, https, lamp

how to install selfsigned https cert to PHPmyadmin (LAMP)?

If any one has done please share the step by step!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create the self signed certificate in OpenSSL](http://sial.org/howto/openssl/self-signed/)

[Configure an SSL Cert in Apache](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm)